# Will QuestDB work on a compressed file system?

Tags: questdb

I am using QuestDB on Linux with Ext4 file system and would like to explore an option of using a for of compression. I cannot find a list of supported File System on official website so wonder has anyone tried to run QuestDB on a filesystem with full compression like ZFS or BTRFS?

Answer (score 1):

QuestDb will work on any file system that allows memory mapped files, so that should include all local file systems. It definitely works on zfs (FreeBSD 12-13) with compressed data sets because I have used it in those scenarios and it performs very well.

Answer (score 0):

ZFS with compression is fully supported on QuestDB Enterprise and it powers all the instances on QuestDB Cloud.

For open source QuestDB, ZFS works, but some users have found out in some cases ZFS might lack consistency and could lead to data corruption. For QuestDB Enterprise and Cloud, a special ZFS driver was developed to address those issues.